# ERROR: heartbeat: Connection lost (ECONNRESET) in sidekiq

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I'm trying to run Sidekiq 5.2.2 on Rails 5.2 but I always get a connection lost error. Below are my server logs:

```
# bundle exec sidekiq -q v2_default,2 -q v2_low -e production
TID-2yed0 INFO: Booting Sidekiq 5.2.2 with redis options {:url=>"redis://myserver.lmf979.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1", :network_timeout=>7, :id=>"Sidekiq-server-PID-3644"}
TID-2yed0 INFO: Running in ruby 2.3.5p376 (2017-09-14 revision 59905) [x86_64-linux]
TID-2yed0 INFO: See LICENSE and the LGPL-3.0 for licensing details.
TID-2yed0 INFO: Upgrade to Sidekiq Pro for more features and support: http://sidekiq.org
TID-2yed0 INFO: Starting processing, hit Ctrl-C to stop
TID-19spa0 ERROR: heartbeat: Connection lost (ECONNRESET)
TID-xhh1g ERROR: Error fetching job: READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.
TID-xhh1g WARN: Redis::CommandError: READONLY You can't write against a read only slave.
TID-xhh1g WARN: /usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.5/gems/redis-4.0.2/lib/redis/client.rb:119:in `call'
```

and this is my config/initializers/sidekiq.rb

```
Sidekiq.configure_server do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://myserver.lmf979.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1', network_timeout: 7 }
end

Sidekiq.configure_client do |config|
    config.redis = { url: 'redis://myserver.lmf979.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1', network_timeout: 7 }
end
```

I verify that I can do ping PONG with the server but I don't know why sidekiq can't connect.

```
# rails c production
Running via Spring preloader in process 7372
Loading production environment (Rails 5.2.1)
2.3.5 :001 > require "redis"
 => false 
2.3.5 :002 > redis = Redis.new(url: 'redis://myserver.lmf979.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1')
 => #<Redis client v4.0.2 for redis://myserver.lmf979.0001.apse1.cache.amazonaws.com:6379/1> 
2.3.5 :003 > redis.ping
 => "PONG" 
2.3.5 :004 >
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You have a clear description: `You can't write against a read only slave`. It means your Redis instance is read-only slave part of the cluster: https://redis.io/topics/cluster-spec

Comment: You are correct. It worked. I was pointing it to the wrong endpoint. I was thinking of too complicated things. I thought something was not working causing it to call a failover instance which is read-only.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was just pointing to a wrong redis endpoint in AWS. Thanks to Pavel Mikhailyuk for pointing out.